# react-router-redux breaks my application state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, redux

I tried to set up react-router-redux in my application, as presented [here](https://github.com/rackt/react-router-redux), but it broke my state.

Here is my store setup :

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { syncHistory, routeReducer } from 'react-router-redux'
import rootReducer from '../reducers'
import Immutable, {Map} from 'immutable'
[Other imports]

const middleware = [X,Y]

const reducer = combineReducers(Object.assign({}, rootReducer, {
  routing: routeReducer
}));

export default function configureStore(initialState, history) {

   const reduxRouterMiddleware = syncHistory(history);
   middleware.push(reduxRouterMiddleware);

   const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(...middleware)(createStore);

   const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer, initialState);     

   return store

}
```

Here is my reducers/index.js :

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import A from './A'
import B from './B'
import C from './C'
...

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  A,
  B,
  C,
  ...
})

export default rootReducer
```

When I console.log in my application my store.getState(), I get : only a routing.location tree.

[image: only routing.location]

If I use "rootReducer" instead of "reducer" when creating my store, I get my normal state tree (A, B, C ...)

[image: no routing.location]

but of course I no longer get the routing.location part I'm interested in ...

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you call `combineReducer` on your own reducers, and then again to merge in the `routing` reducer. I'd just export an object from your own reducers, and do the `combineReducer` call once, where you `Object.assign` the route reducer in.

Comment: Thank you Steven ! Removing the first call to combineReducers (in reducers/index.js) worked ! 
As a reducer is already a function, I though could merge a reducers combination with another reducer ...
Apparently it's not possible :-) ...

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies here:

```
const reducer = combineReducers(Object.assign({}, rootReducer, {
  routing: routeReducer
}));
```

rootReducer is not a plain object, but a function that is returned by the method combineReducer, looking like that:

```
function combination() {
    var state = arguments.length <= 0 || arguments[0] === undefined ? {} : arguments[0];
    var action = arguments[1]; ...
}
```

So what you do is merging an object with a function, which returns the object only. In your case 'routing' only.

Comment: Thank you too @larrydahooster ! Removing the first call to combineReducers (in reducers/index.js) worked ! 
Maybe if I had wrote `combineReducers({rootReducer, routing:routeReducer})` .... ?